# Acts_As_Votable can't vote on other user's posts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, acts-as-votable

I am using the `acts_as_votable` gem and am having an issue with the voting.

I have two models - User and Post. A User is able to vote on a post.

The problem I am having is that the User is only currently able to vote on their own post, but not other users' posts.

I think this is because I have done `@posts.each` and then the user is only being accessed for their own posts, so they can only vote on their own posts. Or the problem is in my index method in my controller.

**Index.html.erb** File:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <div class="user-input">
        <% if post.user.voted_up_on? post %>
            <%= link_to unlike_post_path(post), method: :put do %>
                <%= image_tag("/assets/like.png") %>
            <% end %>
        <% else %>
            <%= link_to like_post_path(post), method: :put do %>
                <%= image_tag("/assets/heart.png") %>
            <% end %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

**Posts_controller** (relevant methods):

```
def index
    @posts = Post.includes(:user).order("created_at DESC") #Possible issue is here??
end

def like
    @post.upvote_by current_user
    redirect_to :back
end

def unlike
    @post.unvote_by current_user
    redirect_to :back
end
```

**Routes**:

```
resources :posts do
    member do 
        put "like", to: "posts#like"
        put 'unlike', to: 'posts#unlike'
    end
end
```

If someone could help me understand why a User is only able to vote on their own posts that would be great.

Comment: Does @posts contain all posts or posts made by the current user only..?

Comment: @BalaKarthik see my controller, but it is: `@posts = Post.includes(:user).order("created_at DESC")`

Comment: Yes i saw that i need to know what does @posts contain?

Comment: I dont understand? @posts is an instance variable and contains `Post.includes(:user).order("created_at DESC")`

Comment: Post.includes(:user).order("created_at DESC")  returns data from your db, I need to know whether this data contains only the posts created by the current_user or posts by all users.

Comment: Oh, it is posts by all users. In the index.html.erb page all the posts are being displayed, although a User can only vote on their own post for some reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.

Had to replace

```
<% if post.user.voted_up_on? post %>
```

with:

```
<% if current_user.liked? post %>
```

I believe it was asking if the creator of the post has voted on the post, whereas  I needed just the current user to see if they have voted on the post.